# Hyperthreading operating system

Tags: hyper-threading

My question is does the operating system has any role in implementing hyperthreading.
Where is hyperthreading implemented in BIOS level or operating system?
Are there OS who does not support hyperthreading but the hardware on which they are running supports hyperthreading?
Is there any microkernel based OS which supports hyperthreading?

Comment: Every operating system will run on a hyperthreaded processor as it appears as a processor with double the cores but it may make poor choices about where to schedule tasks. It may decide to schedule on two particular cores which are in reality two sides of one hyperthreaded core instead of two completely separate cores. This could cause a severe performance drop and is the negative effect David mentions. An OS should be aware of it, but it doesnt need to do much to "implement" it.

Answer (score 2):

Hyperthreading is a CPU feature. But it can have severe negative effects on performance if the operating system's schedule isn't aware of it. Pretty much all modern operating systems that run on CPUs that support hyperthreading have hyperthreading aware schedulers.